# Differentiate swagger UI call from Angular Frontend call

Tags: angular, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I have springboot app and a angular frontend. I am using swagger and making API calls from swagger-ui as well. These APIs are exposed as @RestController so I can call them from Angular as well. 
Right now all my form validations happen at the angular frontend and no validation at the API level. 
My intention is to place API validations but the validations will happen twice if the action is performed from the angular frontend (say saving a form), first from UI and second from API. I am doing this so that the API validates the calls made from swagger-ui. 
Is there a way to differentiate if a call is made from angular frontend or from swagger-ui?
This way I would skip validations if the, say, form data got saved from frontend but still perform the check for swagger calls and keep it clean and not change any implementation as such.
Does swagger provide an api?

Sample code

```
@RestController
@Api(tags = "My api")
@RequestMapping(path = "v1/{apiKey}/myKey")
public class TestController implements TestApi {

  @Override
  public ResponseEntity<GenericResponse> saveAction(
      @ApiParam(value = "Authorization", required = true) 
      @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization", required = true) String authorization,
      @RequestBody SomeDTO someDto, @PathVariable String apiKey,
      @PathVariable String someId, HttpServletRequest request){

      // can I perform some sort of check here
      if(isFromSwagger()){
            performValidation(someDto);
      }

      GenericResponse responseDTO = new GenericResponse();
      return new ResponseEntity<>(responseDTO, responseDTO.getHttpStatusCode());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In modern web apps, it is best practice to validate data twice:

1. In the browser to give immediate feedback to the users.
2. On the server to ensure only valid data is processed further.

The second step on the server is more important as it ensure consistency and security of the back-end systems. It's particularly important for systems where malicious users could profit for manipulating the requests sent to the servers.

The first step is usually used only for simple validations.

So I don't see any reason why you shouldn't validate the data a second time:

- You are implementing the validations on the server side anyway.
- If the data has already been properly validated in the browser, it won't be rejected.
- The performance impact will most likely be negligible.

Comment: While I agree with you, we wanted to avoid the API validation because we have a micro service architecture and the validation required external calls to other apis, which in turn calls more apis. And on top of that everything is hosted on AWS so an added cost as well long with added time. Most basic I can think of is to add and extra parameter with the request and perform validation conditionally using it but this can be easily hacked if you inspect with chrome.

Comment: There are no buts, validate and sanitize your input or you have a major security problem.